# Wake on Lan - Install a client on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, nas, wake-on-lan

this might seem obvious or stupid to somebody, but I can't find anything that helps me yet, besides the fact that I'm not a Linux user.

I've got 2 NAS boxes (Iomega, now Lenovo) IX4-200D and PX6-300D. They're always on.
I've also got a computer already set to start up with a magic packet (works as expected). My router doesn't allow me to send a packet from the internet to the home broadcast address or doesn't like to forward such packet anyways (even though I'm using a DHCP reservation). 
Since the NAS boxes are always on, I was thinking I could just cut the headaches and SSH onto one of them from the WAN and get the magic packet sent from it.

These are the two versions they're running on:
Linux version 3.8.6 (gcc version 4.7.2 (crosstool-NG 1.18.0) )
Linux version 2.6.31.8 (gcc version 4.3.2 (Sourcery G++ Lite 2008q3-72) )

I've only got SSH access to them.
Is there a way to get a WOL client installed on either one of them?

I found a forum a few days ago where a guy had a similar request, it turns out he found a solution but never really gave an answer to his own problem.

Cheers

Comment: what is exactly your problem? try to check if wakeonlan or etherwake installed any of them.

Comment: That is my problem. I have no idea how. I tried to install the code with the piece of commands i found online and it just didn't work, always returned an error. I was thinking, is there a way to get these packages manually downloaded from the internet and then move them and install them on these actual boxes? Ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write this as an answer because of your comment. First, I don't have any of your NAS boxes, neither i had a chance to use them. but according to this [document](http://vincesoft.blogspot.com.tr/2012/01/how-to-install-software-into-your.html).

Your Iomega ix4-200D is using a **package manager** named **ipkg**.

Backup your **/etc/ipkg.conf** file. then delete everything in it. paste the lines below:

```
vi /etc/ipkg.conf
```

add these lines:

```
src cross http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/cs08q1armel/cross/stable
src cross http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/cs08q1armel/cross/unstable
option verbosity 2
option verbose-wget
```

NAS as an embedded device has a read only file system. so we have to use ipkg-opt to get rid of this. run the commands below.

```
ipkg install ipkg-opt
PATH=/opt/bin:$PATH
vi /etc/ld.so.conf
```

then vi will open /etc/ld.so.conf file, Add the line below. save & exit

```
/opt/lib/
```

close your ssh client or disconnect. then reconnect. 
this way your last settings will be applied.

then update your ipkg repository:

```
ipkg update
```

(Note: If you see any wget error. just ignore it's probably caused by verbose output)
then use this command to get a wakeonlan binary:

```
ipkg install perl-wakeonlan
```

if there is any problem during these command. comment here please. we can find a solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for coming back to me. This is what I'm getting when I run ipkg update:
root@IX4-200D-CE1:/# ipkg update
WARNING: Ignoring unknown configuration parameter: ss http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/cs08q1armel/cross/stable
Successfully terminated.

This is what I get when I run ipkg perl-wakeonlan:
root@IX4-200D-CE1:/# ipkg perl-wakeonlan
WARNING: Ignoring unknown configuration parameter: ss http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/cs08q1armel/cross/stable
ipkg: unknown sub-command perl-wakeonlan
ipkg version 0.99.163
usage: ipkg [options...] sub-command [arguments...]

Comment: seems like your config lines are missing some letters or ipkg can not read, the first 9 letters actually like "ss" instead of "src cross", i have updated my answer. please apply it again.

Comment: It did move a bit forward, I'm getting this now when I'm running ipkg update:
ipkg_download: ERROR: Command failed with return value 1: `wget --passive-ftp     -P /tmp/ipkg-RhuVId /Packages'

Before that I can see it resolving the hostname ipkg.nslu2-linux.org and I can see it downloading the package in a temp folder:
Updated list of available packages in /opt/ipkg/lists/cross
An error ocurred, return value: 1.

Comment: You are running ipkg update as root, right? you need to have a write access to /Packages.  if bash prompt ends with an #, that means you are root. $ means ordinary user.

Comment: Yup, I am root (#). Don't get why it fails though.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you!
I found the issue. I forgot to actually disconnect the SSH session. Now, it still gave me the error when downloading but I kept on going ahead with your procedure and it eventually worked! Can you please add a little note at the end to you answer so people know how to use the command?
In my case WOL is located in /opt/bin/wakeonlan. So all I had to do was running the following:
/opt/bin/wakeonlan 00:00:00:00:00:00
That will send a broadcast signal and it didn't work when I specified the actual IP address of my machine. Thanks again!

Comment: I have updated the answer. & it's probably verbose output of wget. (it should report unix 0 instead of 1 :/ ) , glad that you have worked out it. by the there is another package in repo for WOL, wakelan_1.1-2_arm.ipk, to install use  "ipkg install wakelan"